# Swagger API which is having query string

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I want to deploy an API which is having query string.This is the API

```
v1/products?q=circuit breaker&locale=en-GB&pageSize=8&pageNo=1&project=GLOBAL
```

Here is how i am implementing

```
"/v1/products?q={searchText}&locale={ctrCode}&pageSize={pageSize}&pageNo={pageNo}&project={project}&country={country}":{  
         "get":{  
            "tags":[  
               "Search Text"
            ],
            "summary":"Get Products by searching text, countrycode, page number, pagesize, project and country(optional)",
            "description":"Get Products by searching text, countrycode, page number, pagesize, project and country(optional)",
            "operationId":"getProductName",
            "produces":[  
               "application/json",
               "application/xml"
            ],
            "parameters":[  
               {  
                  "name":"searchText",
                  "in":"path",
                  "description":"The Product that needs to be fetched",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"ctrCode",
                  "in":"path",
                  "description":"The Product locale needs to be fetched. Example=en-GB, fr-FR, etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"pageSize",
                  "in":"path",
                  "description":"The Product PageSize that needs to be fetched. Example=10, 20 etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"number"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"pageNo",
                  "in":"path",
                  "description":"The Product pageNo that needs to be fetched. Example=1,2 etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"number"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"project",
                  "in":"path",
                  "description":"The Project that needs to be fetched. Example=Mypact, DSL etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"country",
                  "in":"header",
                  "description":"The Country that needs to be fetched. Example=France, India etc.",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ],
            "responses":{  
               "200":{  
                  "description":"successful operation",
                  "schema":{  
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Products"
                  }
               },
               "400":{  
                  "description":"Invalid Product_id supplied"
               },
               "404":{  
                  "description":"Product not found"
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

The country is optional parameter in this. I want the URL should display country only when if user enter some value, else it should not be displayed in the URL.

Comment: same problem...swagger is stupid here...

Answer (score 28):

You can't describe query parameters as part of the path in Swagger. You have to declare those explicitly as query parameters.

```
"/v1/products":{  
         "get":{  
            "tags":[  
               "Search Text"
            ],
            "summary":"Get Products by searching text, countrycode, page number, pagesize, project and country(optional)",
            "description":"Get Products by searching text, countrycode, page number, pagesize, project and country(optional)",
            "operationId":"getProductName",
            "produces":[  
               "application/json",
               "application/xml"
            ],
            "parameters":[  
               {  
                  "name":"searchText",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Product that needs to be fetched",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"ctrCode",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Product locale needs to be fetched. Example=en-GB, fr-FR, etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"pageSize",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Product PageSize that needs to be fetched. Example=10, 20 etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"number"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"pageNo",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Product pageNo that needs to be fetched. Example=1,2 etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"number"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"project",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Project that needs to be fetched. Example=Mypact, DSL etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"country",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Country that needs to be fetched. Example=France, India etc.",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ],
            "responses":{  
               "200":{  
                  "description":"successful operation",
                  "schema":{  
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Products"
                  }
               },
               "400":{  
                  "description":"Invalid Product_id supplied"
               },
               "404":{  
                  "description":"Product not found"
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: that is not my problem , the problem is if user does not give anything for country(parameter) the country={country} should not be displayed in the URL

Comment: You are right, I forget a certain fix. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 10):

Your IN parameter needs to be "query" not "path"

This should work:

```
"parameters": [
  {  
    "name":"country",
    "in":"query",
    "description":"The Country that needs to be fetched. Example=France, India etc.",
    "required":false,
    "type":"string"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In editor.swagger.io you can do it like that:

- no params in your routing
- params' attribute 'in' has to be 'query'

```
/v1/products:  
  get:
    tags:
       - Search Text       
    summary: Get Products by searching text, countrycode, page number, pagesize, project and country(optional)
    description: Get Products by searching text, countrycode, page number, pagesize, project and country(optional)
    operationId: getProductName
    parameters: 
      - name: searchText
        in: query
        description: The Product that needs to be fetched
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: ctrCode
        in: query
        description: The Product locale needs to be fetched. Example=en-GB, fr-FR, etc.
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: pageSize
        in: query
        description: The Product PageSize that needs to be fetched. Example=10, 20 etc.
        required: true
        schema:        
          type: number
      - name: pageNo
        in: query
        description: The Product pageNo that needs to be fetched. Example=1,2 etc.
        required: true
        schema:
          type: number
      - name: project
        in: query
        description: The Project that needs to be fetched. Example=Mypact, DSL etc.
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
```