# How to pass query parameters in Node js Swagger.json?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I am trying to pass query parameters from request URL in NodeJS swagger.json. But I am getting undefined.

here is the URL
`reset/password?email=myname@mail.com`

On NodeJS swagger

```js
"parameters": [{
    "name": "Parameters",
    "in": "",
    "required": true,
    "type": "string",
    "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/resetPassword",
    }
}],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger API which is having query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251585/swagger-api-which-is-having-query-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example for passing query parameter through JSON:

URL : reset/password?email=myname@mail.com

```
parameters:
        - in: path
          name: email
          type: string
          required: true
          description: description of parameter
```

Comment: `in: path` means a path parameter, as in `/reset/password/myname@email.com`, not a query parameter

Answer (score 4):

Change this code: `"in": "query"`

Answer (score 3):

Your parameter definition should look like this:

```
"parameters": [
    {
      "name": "email",
      "in": "query",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "email",
      "required": true
    }
  ]
```

`in: query` indicates that the parameter is passed in the query string.

`name: ...` is the parameter name (in your example - `email`).

`type: string` and `format: email` indicate the parameter type. Query parameters require a primitive `type` (string, number, etc.) or an array type, but they cannot `$ref` definitions. `format` is an optional hint for tools that will process your OpenAPI definition.

Check out the [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/) guide for more details.

Comment: Great! If this answer helped you, consider [marking it as an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/131247) to help the future visitors.