# Swagger errors shows a need to define a parameter in the path or operation level

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I am getting the error below:

> Declared path parameter "imageId" needs to be defined as a path
>   parameter at either the path or operation level

This is the snapshot of my swagger definition

```
 '/api/v1/images/{unitnumber}/{type}/{imageId}':
        delete:
          tags:
            - Images
          summary: 'Summary'
          description: "Description"
          operationId: DeleteImage
          consumes: []
          produces:
            - application/json
          parameters:
            - name: unitnumber
              in: path
              required: true
              type: string
            - name: type
              in: path
              required: true
              type: string
            - name: imageId
              in: query
              required: false
              type: string
          responses:
            '400':
              description: Bad Request
              schema:
                $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
            '401':
              description: Unauthorized
              schema:
                type: string
            '500':
              description: Server Error
              schema:
                $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
```

I only can get rid of the error if I take the `imageId` and changing to `path` instead `query` which is not the intention

```
           - name: imageId
                  in: path
                  required: true
                  type: string
```

Any idea of what I need to change to have this working?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Swagger API which is having query string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30251585/113116)

Answer (score 9):

The path string `/api/v1/images/{unitnumber}/{type}/{imageId}` means that `imageId` is a path parameter so it must be `in: path`.

If `imageId` is supposed to be a query parameter, as in `/api/v1/images/{unitnumber}/{type}?imageId=...`, you need to change the path string to `/api/v1/images/{unitnumber}/{type}`. Query parameters [should not be mentioned in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30252104/113116), they are defined in the `parameters` section alone.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a query parameter using a question mark as follows:

```
/api/v1/images/{unitnumber}/{type}/{?imageId}
```

Answer (score 0):

(The question is not clear in the context of the question so:)

If you are using OpenAPI and in a C# context:

```
 [OpenApiParameter("imageId", In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The image identifier")]
```

The error occurs in some pipelines that use OpenAPI. Place the code snippet above your Azure Function/ Endpoint / Controller and the error should be fixed.