# How to define a path with two optional parameters in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I registered at SwaggerHub and created a new API using OpenAPI 3.0. In my API, the `/tasks` path has 2 non-required parameters, but I can not set them as not required - the editor shows the "Not allowed Values" error.

Here's my API definition:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: A Simple IP Address API
  title: VTasks
  version: v1
servers:
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
  - description: SwaggerHub API Auto Mocking
    url: https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/petrogromovo/Vtasks/1.0.0
  - description: SwaggerHub API Auto Mocking
    url: http://hosting.tk

paths:

  /tasks:
    get:
      tags:
        - tasks
      summary: Get paginated / filtered tasks listing
      operationId: tasks
      parameters:
        - name: page
          in: path
          description: The page number to be fetched. If missed default 1.
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
        - name: order_by
          in: path
          description: The order_by  be fetched. 
          required: false  // ERROR : should be equal to one of the allowed values allowedValues: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: filter
          in: path
          description: The filter for title field. 
          required: false // ERROR : should be equal to one of the allowed values allowedValues: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
        '400':
          description: Invalid tasks supplied
        '404':
          description: tasks were not found
```

But if I remove the `required` attributes, I get 2 errors:

> should have required property 'required'
>   missingProperty: required

What is the valid syntax?

Comment: Related: [Swagger errors shows a need to define a parameter in the path or operation level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56962805/113116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are these parameters supposed to be path parameters or query parameters?

**Path parameters** (`in: path`) are part of the endpoint path, and as such must be indicated by `{...}` in the path template:

```
paths:
  /tasks/{page}/{order_by}/{filter}:
```

Path parameters are always required, i.e. they must have `required: true`.

**Query parameters** are send in the query string, e.g. `/tasks?page=...&order_by=...`. To use query parameters, change the parameter location to `in: query`.

More information: [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/)